# nonType error when trying to use csv file to store parameters in my class

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a csv file as a way to store my instances.

```
@classmethod
def instantiate_from_csv(cls):
    with open("items.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        items = list(reader)

    for item in items:
        Item(
            name = item.get('name'),
            price = int(item.get('price')),
            quantity = int(item.get('quantity')),
        )
```

and my csv file literally only has:

```
name,price,quantity
"Phone",100,1
"Laptop",1000,3
"Cable",10,5
"Mouse",50,5
"Keyboard",75,5
```

I was expecting to return those into the parameters I had in my class but got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Code\object oriented programming\testing.py", line 42, in <module>
    Item.instantiate_from_csv()
  File "c:\Code\object oriented programming\testing.py", line 33, in instantiate_from_csv
    price = int(item.get('price')),
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: That error means that that `item` does not have a `price` column. It may be a trailing line at the end of the file? Double check `items` by printing the values out to verify that the data is what you think it should be.

Comment: Yeah, add a `print(item)` in the loop. That said, I couldn't reproduce the issue by adding a trailing blank line, but the print could show what the actual problem is.

Comment: Beside the point, but this method doesn't return anything and never uses `cls`, so that's gonna cause issues for you later, but it's not relevant to this problem. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like making a [mre] (e.g. include the definition of `Item` so that we can run the code ourselves without having to infer).

Comment: Double-check the contents of your csv file to make sure they are exactly as shown, with no extra spaces etc.